# how to print a variable javascript in a onmousedown event?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I get a value from `<li>` element with a `onclick` event.

I need show the variable inside a "onmousedown" before I click. Is it possible ?

```
<li id="'+val+'" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">Animal</li>

  <script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id){
  var id  = clicked_id;                
}
</script>

<button type="submit"  onmousedown="try { rrApi.addToBasket(ID HERE) } catch(e) {}" class="add_to_cart"></button>
```

Comment: Shouldnt you call the reply_click in mouse down? I made a simple fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/d3mauyp0/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work in the way i want. i need print the variable inside the try { rrApi.addToBasket(NAME HERE) } .  I already have the variable obtained from an < li > element. and I need it to show up before I click.